# Scroll DataGridRows including RowDetailstemplate using up/down arrow

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have datagrid with nested datagrid inside  the Rowdetailstemplate.

I want to scroll all the datagrid rows using the keyboard up/down arrow keys.

For example,look the data below

1.MainDatagridRow
     i NestedDatagridRow

```
ii NestedDatagridRow

iii NestedDatagridRow
```

2.MainDatagridRow
     a NestedDatagridRow

```
b NestedDatagridRow

c NestedDatagridRow
```

I want to scroll the Each rows including the NestedDatagridrow seqentially by using the up/down arrows, please do needful.